# If $a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta=m, a\cos^2\phi+b\sin^2\phi=n, a\tan\theta=b\tan\phi$, prove that $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\, a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta=m$, $\, a\cos^2\phi+b\sin^2\phi=n$, $\, a\tan\theta=b\tan\phi$.  Prove that
>
> $$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$

I've tried setting :
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\tan\theta}{\tan\phi}=k
\\ a=bk
\\
\tan\theta=k\tan\phi
$$

and substituting these in the equations. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? A shorter path to the answer would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta=m\to a\tan^2 \theta+b=m\sec^2\theta\\
a\tan^2\theta +b=m(1+\tan^2\theta)\to \tan^2\theta=\frac{m-b}{a-m}$$

so, using the same idea

$$\tan^2\phi=\frac{n-a}{b-n}$$

we also have that

$$\frac{\tan^2 \theta}{\tan^2 \phi}=\frac{b^2}{a^2}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yeah. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$a\tan\theta=b\tan\phi=c,\;$ say.  Then,

$\tan\theta=c/a, \; \tan\phi=c/b\;$ so that

$\;\sin\theta=c/\sqrt{c^2+a^2},\;  \cos\theta=a/\sqrt{c^2+a^2},\; \sin\phi=c/\sqrt{c^2+b^2}, \; \cos\phi=b/\sqrt{c^2+b^2}$.

From the first two equations, we get

$m=\dfrac{ac^2}{c^2+a^2}+\dfrac{ba^2}{c^2+b^2}, \; n=\dfrac{ab^2}{c^2+b^2}+\dfrac{bc^2}{c^2+b^2}$.

Then, $ab(m+n)=\dfrac{ab(a+b)(c^2+ab)^2}{(c^2+a^2)(c^2+b^2)}=mn(a+b)$.